# Angular open documents inline

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app, that uses autorization with token. In every app ajax call i pass autorization header.

Now i need to open images and pdfs. I need to open images in a new tab (inline). Not to download (attachment).

I have a url that returns me a image with the correct header of the image or pdf and set correctly inline content disposition header and conten t type.

I found the followind code to download the image and open it. But it code force download, I need an alternative to open inline.

```
return $http.get(url_file, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
                .success(function (data) {
                    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/png'});
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                    window.location.assign(fileURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window.open method to load you file, like this:

```
function newTab(url){
  var w=window.open(url, '_blank');
  w.focus();
}
```